# What is wrong with my Angular binding to a boolean?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following html, trying to 'hide' a div based on a boolean value:

**Listing 1:**

```
<span>{{AcceptFna.MainLifeFullName}}</span>
<span>{{AcceptFna.ProposerIsMainLife}}</span>
<div ng-if="AcceptFna.ProposerIsMainLife">Waaah!</div>
```

In the Chrome console, I can see that `AcceptFna.ProposerIsMainLife` is true, when the 2nd span in Listing 1 is highlighted, with the following command:

> angular.element($0).scope().AcceptFna.IsProposerMainLife
>   <-true

So I would expect to see both spans and the `ng-if` div, but only the first span is visible, and the 'calculated' html is:

```
<span class="ng-binding">Smith</span>
<span class="ng-binding"></span>
<!-- ngIf: AcceptFna.ProposerIsMainLife -->
```

So, it looks like `ProposerIsMainLife` is defined and true on the current scope, yet is failing to bind. What could be wrong here?

Comment: Have you tried using `ng-show` ?

Comment: @tektiv Turns out it was a typo on my part, ouch. But, I wanted to use `ng-if` rather, because I have required fields in the part I want to hide, and with `ng-show` the required fields still trigger a validation error even though they're 'missing'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a simple name error:

```
<div ng-if="AcceptFna.ProposerIsMainLife">

angular.element($0).scope().AcceptFna.IsProposerMainLife <-true
```

"proposer is" vs "is proposer". Choose a naming convention and *stick* to it :)

Comment: How embarrassing! Thanks, I was copying from two different files into the html.